# gwt-dev includes httpclient 4.0 how do I get around that in a maven env?

Tags: java, gwt, maven, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

My Project uses httpcore 4.1... the gwt-dev 2.3 jar includes 4.0... which is not forwards compatible. If I hack 4.0 out of the jar and trick maven into using that, my generators work and my code compiles without additional changes. How can I do this without hacking my maven repo such that I create a reproducible build? Do I really need the full gwt-dev jar if I just want to add a generator to my gwt build? I must be missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man... this is what I get for coding way past my bed time... the easy answer was to move the httpclient dep above the gwt-dev dep in my pom dependencies... problem solved, no jar hacking required... it's amazing what a couple hours of sleep will do for your brain function.

Comment: You would have to ensure gwt-dev jar never gets into WEB-INF folder. There is not classpath hierarchy there.

Answer (score 0):

If by "generator" you mean a GWT [Generator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/ext/Generator.html), then yes, you need gwt-dev, and you have to play by its rules re. dependencies. Welcome to "classpath hell"!

To be exact though, your generator has to play the gwt-dev rules, but the rest of your code (particularly server-side) doesn't have to. In that case, you'd like to put your generator in a separate project to better manage dependencies (your generator would depend on gwt-dev with scope=provided, and gwt-dev would indeed be provided by the DevMode/Compiler itself, or in Maven the gwt-maven-plugin).
I believe it's a good practice to separate client code from server code in distinct modules anyway.